# How to detect HOVER/CLICKS in Starling button with LeapMotionAS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework, leap-motion

I want to click on Starling buttons using the LeapMotion SCREEN_TAP gesture.
This is possible? To click the Starling button and see the regular push/shrink effect on it using this gesture?

If not...what is the best approach to achieve this?

Any help is welcome!
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could do this (I have never done it but I think it should work):

1. Check whether the tap's coordinates are over the button
2. If they are, swap the button's texture: `var up:Texture = btn.upState; //save reference
   btn.upState = btn.downState;`
3. After X milliseconds swap them back: `btn.upState = up;`

Comment: Hey Fygo!
Let me try to do it.
I suppose that touch emulation (leap page Java example: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Java/Guides/Leap_Touch_Emulation.html#id2 ) is required to achieve this, right?

I will try to translate this example to AS3 (:( no AS3 example!) and then follow your advice.

Regards!